# Class Name: Append DTO or Entity

Tags: c#, serialization, naming-conventions, dto

Is there any preference on either appending `DTO` or `Entity` to a class name?

Is there any standard around this?

1 Class is used by ORM (EntityFramework) and the other class is used for serialization.

The reason for this is so that there is no duplication of all fields as the EntityFramework is a wrapper around the DTO class(most but not all properties).

The DTO class is in a shared library, and decoupled from EF.

E.g. Which of these is the most common/standard approach?

```
// 1.
MyNamespace.Entities.MyClass
MyNamespace.Models  .MyClassDto


// 2.
MyNamespace.Entities.MyClassEntity
MyNamespace.Models  .MyClass


// 3.
MyNamespace.Entities.MyClassEntity
MyNamespace.Models  .MyClassDto
```

Comment: This is largely subject of personal preference. A suitable rule of thumb: is it a data transfer object? Go ahead with the `Dto` suffix. Is it a database entity / the actual data? Leave it without any suffixes.

Comment: Where can I ask a quesiton like this? Reddit?

Answer (score 1):

In my personal experience your third example is the only implementation I have worked with and it is the one I would argue for because the intent of the object you are working with will always be clear whereas with the other two it only becomes clear when looking at both objects together.

That being said as long as your team comes to an agreement on which to use any would work.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you typically don't want to put implementation details into class names for similar reasons to why you don't want to use Hungarian Notation.

If there's a bit of code that needs to work with both types and differentiate between them, another option is including aliased using statements like this:

```
using entities = MyNamespace.Entities;
using dto = MyNamespace.Models;

//in code
var myClassEntity = new entities.MyClass();
var myClassDto = new dto.MyClass();

//work with both
```

My assumption is that the code that needs to work with both types is limited to an isolated library, and that client code typically works with one, not both types.

Comment: That's what I currently have :-( It's a pain, and it's ugly, especially when you have a generic for which you have to keep passing it around everywhere + a bunch of tools are reporting this as a critical problem which my team frown upon :-(

Comment: The trick is making it so that the consumers can only reference one type, not both so it's only needed in data access/conversion code. If the "Entities" classes are only used for data access, then encapsulate them inside a library such that only that library has to deal with both. The only class that should have to deal with both types should be some simple converter, then only a single resolvable type should be passed around from there. Otherwise, you might be using a name change to hide a possible engineering problem.